# How does Android device know what is "up" when it boots up

Tags: android, orientation

If I take my device and hang it upside down and restart it, the start screen will always be oriented in the same rotation. There is no rotation change event and using the following code in my own app does not yield the rotation either:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int rotation = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

I am running this on Android 2.3. I suspect that one of the sensors provides the orientation as to what is up but can't find any API that gives you the orientation. In fact, you don't even have to hang the device upside down. You can lay it down or position it in any orientation and the start screen always orientates itself correctly. The start screen never flips or changes orientation at all.

Comment: It uses gravity; it's possible to read peripherals at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accelerometer gives orientation. Direction of gravity is bottom ) So android won't be able to determine orientation in space )

Comment: I wonder if it would re-calibrate itself to be less-sensitive to motion events to avoid constant reorientations.

Comment: Not clear. But I think you gave me a hint. It's the Gravity sensor? Reading the docs, it says "The gravity sensor provides a three dimensional vector indicating the direction and magnitude of gravity.". So I can determine "up" from gravity values?

Comment: Year, Accelerometer is a gravity senson in all android devices I know. It gives 3d vector of force applied to a device.

Comment: You say that the accelerometer is a gravity sensor as though it's the same thing. But the docs indicate two separate sensors: an accelerometer and a gravity sensor although it does mention the accelerometer as having some gravity capabilities. So which one should I be using? Presumably the gravity sensor.

Comment: Android doesn't force hardware to be of some paticular type. Documentation describes android in a broad way. Nowdays gravity sensor  is a vurtual device. It takes accel values (+Gyro on some devices), filters and processes them, and calculates gravity vector to determine orientation. E.g. on my nexus7 orientation is determined based on accel output. Theres in no any special hardware. You can find nexus7 schematics on web.

Answer (score 0):

You may safely assume that accelerometer chip is soldered to motherboard in proper direction.
Basically it provides 3 numbers  -  vector components for acceleration applied to device 
( if device is laying somewhere immobile,  this vector is directed up,   and its absolute value is earth gravity ).  Thank proper soldering,  vector components are aligned  with 
device axes -  just check sign of them to determine which part is higheer than other

Answer (score 0):

The accelerometer detects orientation in reference to gravity. If you hang your phone upside down and restart it, the accelerometer returns "up" as to the bottom of the screen, but the makers of the component accounted for this beforehand. Because of this, the accelerometer detects its orientation in reference to itself also. It is able to detect the differences in the "up" that aligns with gravity and the "up" that aligns with itself. Therefore, the "up" returned by `wm.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()` is switched from "up" to "down" because the accelerometer knows it is upside down (basically).

This is a very rough concept, but is the general idea.

Comment: That doesn't explain why getRotation doesn't return the correct value immediately after startup in code such as a service. I eventually discovered that Settings > Display > Auto Rotate Screen must be enabled in order for getRotation to work. But if that setting is disabled, the device still orientates its itself correctly, which means that it probably is relying entirely on the accelerometer and not using getRotation itself.

Comment: Correct. Disabling auto rotation more or less disables the accelerometer also, unless applications explicitly use the accelerometer for an implemented feature. During the device's bootup, the "up" direction is set to the same direction, no matter which way gravity says is "up." This is why the rotation of the screen is the same even when booted upside down. The device can tell what is "up" due to gravity and what is "up" on the actual device, separate from gravity.